# How to pass images from collection view to collection view

Tags: xcode, swift4

I am struggled in passing images from collection view cell to another collection view cell.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main" , bundle: nil)
        let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImageViewController") as! ImageViewController
        let imageItem = image[indexPath.row]
        vc.images = imageItem.image
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

then in ImageViewController

```
class ImageViewController: UIViewController ,UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var imageCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var image: string!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.imageCollectionView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return image.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell = imageCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! imageCollectionViewCell
  let url: URL = NSURL(string: image)! as URL
  cell.images.af_setImage(withURL: url)
  return cell
  }
```

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: please tell me , is these two collection view in the same page or in different page?

Comment: one collection view in 1st view controller and next in another view controller  and I get image from server @HamzaAlmass

Comment: please share your code in the imageViewController which receive the image are you tried to display it from viewDidLoad Or viewWillAppear?

Comment: i have edited my question please check it @HamzaAlmass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import UIKit

//for the firstVC

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main" , bundle: nil)
    if let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImageViewController") as? ImageViewController
        vc.reciveImageFromFirstVC = image[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
     }
```

// for the second page image view controller

```
class ImageViewController : UIViewController {

    var image:String!

    var reciveImageFromFirstVC : String? {
        didSet {
            guard let reciveImg = reciveImageFromFirstVC else {
                print("Can't get image for some reason")
                return}
            self.image = reciveImg
            self.imageCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = imageCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! imageCollectionViewCell
        let url: URL = NSURL(string: image)! as URL
        cell.images.af_setImage(withURL: url)
        return cell
    }


}
```

i hope i helped you

thanks

Comment: thanks this method worked,but pass only one image in didselect function